# Suspend validation of an input field when the field is disabled

Tags: eclipse, data-binding

In my Eclipse RCP app, I have a configuration form which determines how to fetch a file. The options are:

- either fetch the file via a SAP web service (checkbox)
- or fetch direct from a shared folder (text box).

The controls are bound to the view model and the text box has a validator to ensure that the contents are valid. If the checkbox is selected the text box is disabled.

[image]

I would like to disable the text box validation when the text box field is disabled. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I don't see anything in the data binding code that can disable the validator. So you would either have to remove the validator from the UpdateValueStrategy or make the validator aware of the enabled state.

Comment: @greg-449 Disabling the validator itself is straightforward. The problem I found was how to inform the 'owner' of the validator when the enabled state changes.

Comment: calling `DataBindingContext.updateTargets()` and `updateModels()` runs the various validators again